# How to fetch Root namespace defined in a .NET Assembly using Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have loaded a Assembly using following code

```
Assembly.LoadFrom(ProjectDllPath);
```

Now this asssembly contains only one namespace and some classes in that namespace and I want to fetch the name of that Namespace . What is the syntax to fetch that name.

Comment: Why is it not possible? Hmm, its should be possible to [list types](http://towardsnext.wordpress.com/2008/09/17/listing-types-and-methods-of-assembly-reflection/) in assembly, then take `FullName` of type. Am I wrong? Was posting answer when got that bar on top saying I can't post answer anymore. Good? Bad? =P

Comment: @Sinatr: The question has been answered before. Then it should be closed as duplicate.